# Is the word "crossroads" used when it's outside of the country? If yes, does country refer to "a nation" or "small settlements outside large towns"?

Tags: meaning

Is she saying (https://youtu.be/WCfV7OkNCDo?t=461) "we do actually use *crossroads* when it's outside of the country"?

if yes, does country refer to "a nation" or "small settlements outside large towns"?

Comment: No, she says "...when it's out in the country", referring to roads that are outside towns. Apparently Americans use _intersection_ for a crossroads in an urban area.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for your comments. Just for sure, did you actually hear the words, rather than taking a loot at the transcript?

Comment: I didn't look at the transcript. She says _out in_, not _outside of_.

Comment: @KateBunting  Thanks a lot! Are "outside of the country" and "out in the country" interchangeable here?

Comment: No. "Out in the country" (that is, out of town) means in rural areas. "Outside [of[] the country" would mean beyond the border of the nation.